# Hibernate one to many mapping where one class has a composite primary key on many side

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to query two tables joined by inner join using hibernate.

Two tables are as follows.

CREATE TABLE `systemuser` (
    `system_user_id` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`system_user_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `role` (
    `system_user_id` INT(20) NOT NULL ,
    `role_id` INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`system_user_id,role_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `FK_SYSTEM_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`system_user_id`) REFERENCES `systemuser` (`system_user_id`)
)

These two tables have a one to many relationship.

Bean classes for these tow are as follows.

```
@Entity(name = "role")
@IdClass(RoleCompositeKey.class)

public class Role extends implements java.io.Serializable {

private int roleId =0;
private int systemUserId =0;
private SystemUser systemUser;

public Role(){

}

public void setRoleId(int roleId){
 this.roleId = roleId;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "role_Id")
public int getRoleId(){
    return roleId;
}

public void setSystemUserId(int systemUserId){
    this.systemUserId = systemUserId;
}

@Id
@Column(name="system_user_id")
public int getSystemUserId(){
    return systemUserId;
}


public void setSystemUser(SystemUser systemUser){
    this.systemUser= systemUser;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "system_user_id", nullable = false)
public SystemUser getSystemUser(){
    return systemUser;
}

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "systemuser",uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "system_user_id"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user_name") })

public class SystemUser {

private int systemUserId = 0;
private String userName            = null;


private Set<Role> roleList;

public SystemUser(){

}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@Column(name = "user_name")
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}


public void setSystemUserId(int systemUserId){
    this.systemUserId = systemUserId;
}

@Id
@Column(name="system_user_id")
public int getSystemUserId(){
    return systemUserId;
}

public void setRole(Set<Role> roleList){
    this.roleList = roleList;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "systemUser")
public Set<Role> getRole(){
    return roleList;
}
}
```

but I'm getting an error saying

"........Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ....beans.Role column: system_user_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")"

Please can anyone help me? Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Repeated column in mapping for entity". You declare in role, the relationship two times. Remove this one.

```
    @Id
   @Column(name="system_user_id")
   public int getSystemUserId(){
        return systemUserId;
   }
```

And just leave this one

```
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "system_user_id", nullable = false)
       public SystemUser getSystemUser(){
           return systemUser;
       }
```

Comment: Thank you paul. This solve the above exception. But then JBOSS gives another error when I'm trying to up my server.
The error is "Servlet Init threw load() exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V"

Comment: No problem. That´s error is another thing, you need to open another ticket here. Please vote the response and mark as correct.